# connect ingress to external service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to connect ingress on kubernetes to external service, for example `google.com` whose ip is `172.217.21.14`.

So when I go to `service.test.ai` it sends me to `google.com`
but it doesn't work.

Here are the manifests:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    #kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  name: external-service
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service.test.ai
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: external-ip
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-ip
spec:
  ports:
  - name: app
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-ip
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 172.217.21.14
  ports:
  - name: app
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sends" me? Do you want to proxy the request to the website (like google.com) or just redirect it?

Comment: @thomas i mean just redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you external service have DNS name domain you can use the external service in kubernetes.

so flow will be something like :

```
ingress > service > external service 

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: google.com
```

now ingress will be something like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: externalNameservice
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

if you want to use the IP address you can go with your approach only

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-ip
spec:
  ports:
  - name: app
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5678
  clusterIP: None
  type: ClusterIP

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-ip
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 172.217.21.14
  ports:
  - name: app
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
```

check the service `clusterIP` also check for the SSL annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
```

**UPdate** :

as you mention if you want to redirect or rewrite the traffic I am just sharing a small example for both

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: wordpress-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($host = 'www.example.io' ) {
        rewrite ^ https://example.io$request_uri permanent;
      }
      if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://exmple.io$request_uri;
      }
      if ($scheme = 'http') {
        return 301 https://example.io$request_uri;
      }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "True"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "True"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~ /test-check {
         rewrite /test-check https://app.example.io$uri permanent;
      }
      location = /login {
         rewrite / https://app.example.io/login permanent;
      }
  name: wordpress-prod-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: wordpress-site
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  - host: www.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: wordpress-site
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.io
    - www.example.io
    secretName: www-ssl-certificate
```

Comment: i just tried it as it's but it doesn't work

Comment: just want to redirect ?

Comment: @AhmedNageh i have updated the anser please check section update. it has example for redirect and rewrite in ingress.

Answer (score 0):

[Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) are meant to load balance traffic to pods in your cluster. I do not think you can have a service pointing to an external endpoint. If you want to do that, set it up in your ingress.

Answer (score 0):

If it's `redirect` you're after then nginx ingress controller has annotation called [permanent redirect](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#permanent-redirect):

> This annotation allows to return a permanent redirect (Return Code
> 301) instead of sending data to the upstream. For example
> `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: https://www.google.com` would redirect everything to Google.

So your ingress should look like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: "www.google.com"
  name: external-service
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service.test.ai
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: external-ip
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

And here's test:

```sh
➜  ~ curl  -H "Host:  service.test.ai"  192.168.49.2/test -v

*   Trying 192.168.49.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.49.2 (192.168.49.2) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> Host:  service.test.ai
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sun, 30 May 2021 19:27:52 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 162
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: www.google.com
```

The below ingress example if in case you'd want to redirect the request along with some parameters after the `/`. In that case you would need
`configuration-snippet` or `server-snippet`:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    #kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      return 301 http://www.google.com$request_uri;
  name: external-service
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service.test.ai
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: external-ip
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

With this, if I curl my ingress it's being redirected along with the path:

```
➜  ~ curl  -H "Host:  service.test.ai"  192.168.49.2/service-query-ai  -v

*   Trying 192.168.49.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.49.2 (192.168.49.2) port 80 (#0)
> GET /service-query-ai HTTP/1.1
> Host:  service.test.ai
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sun, 30 May 2021 19:31:57 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 162
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://www.google.com/service-query-ai
```

Comment: so it's just this ingress file or i need to deploy anything else

Comment: i mean do i need kind:service and kind:endpoints at your approach

Comment: Last time I checked this service endpoint was not needed. I will have to recheck this tomorrow.

Comment: i tried to deploy it using just kind:ingress the same yaml yu put at ur answer and i got "<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>"

Comment: I just tested this without any service that backs the ingress and redirect is working.